# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I run `hadoop jar /home/apache-nutch-2.3.1/runtime/deploy/apache-nutch-2.3.1.job org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5`
But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:316)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

I created a urls/seed.text file in /home/apache-nutch-2.3.1/build/ that contains the following URLs: 
`http://nutch.apache.org`
   `http://apache.org`
and I edited conf/regex-urlfilter.txt as follow:
`+^http://([a-z0-9]*\.)*apache.org/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl has been removed since version 1.8. It's recommended to run the shell script bin/crawl instead. It will launch Hadoop jobs for every step of a crawl: inject, generate, fetch, parse, etc.